# Select nested property values in LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am fairly new to Linq and I am starting to try and filter lists and IEnumerable content without using foreach loops. In this case I want to retreive a nested property if it meets a given criteria.

Here is what I have so far:

```
IEnumerable<GroupTourData> test = 
    web_service_item.TourInstances
    .Where(x => x.Availability.Where(a => a.Price > 0 && a.Grade == string.Empty)
    .Count() > 0);
```

What I want to achieve here is an IEnumerable list of all of the prices in the matching criteria. I though this would be obtainable by adding .SelectMany(a.Price) to the end of this statement but that seems to error out in Visual Studio.

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which type of error? Can You post error?

Comment: should there be `.Include("Availability")` in your code?

Comment: you just want the prices? then you just had your `SelectMany` in the wrong positions: `web_service_item.TourInstances.SelectMany(ti => ti.Availability).Where(a => a.Price > 0 && a.Grade == string.Empty).Select(a => a.Price);`

Comment: Instead of second `Where`, use `Any` to return boolean value.

Comment: `.Count()` takes a lambda expression, so you can do `.Where(x => x.Availability.Count(a => a.Price > 0 && a.Grade == string.Empty) > 0)`

Comment: @Carsten That was exactly what I needed. If you add that as an Answer I will mark it as the correct solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok seems as this solves the issue:

if you just want the `price`s? then you just had your `SelectMany` in the wrong position:

```
web_service_item
    .TourInstances
    .SelectMany(ti => ti.Availability)
    .Where(a => a.Price > 0 && a.Grade == string.Empty)
    .Select(a => a.Price);
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your data schema and tables... Have you tried including your sub-entities using `Include`?

```
IEnumerable<GroupTourData> test = web_service_item
    .TourInstances
    .Include("Availability")
    .Where(x => x
        .Availability
        .Any(a => a.Price > 0 && a.Grade == string.Empty)
    );
```

Comment: You've been bit faster then me ;) Your solution is realizing exactly what i suggested in comment to the question. Cheers, Maciej

Comment: @MaciejLos While adding my answer I haven't seen any new comments comming in, but you're right I've added `Any` just as you've suggested.